# Limits Question of (0/0) Form

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

How do I solve this question? Please explain if possible how the method striked you too.

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+x}-\sqrt{p-x}}{\sqrt{q+x}-\sqrt{q-x}}\right)$$

I tried double rationalising the problem, but just ended up with this:

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{q+x}+\sqrt{q-x}}{\sqrt{p+x}+\sqrt{p-x}}\right)$$

I thought of squaring the limit, but that doesn't work too, just ends up with cancelling 2x in the end. I have absolutely no idea on how to proceed. I haven't yet learnt Calculus, just started with Limits.

Comment: Use $\sqrt{u}-\sqrt{v}=\frac{u-v}{\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v}}$ twice.

Comment: Write down your own work, with or without the nice and helpful comment by J.G.,  lest your question be downvoted and even closed.

Comment: Let me suggest that you take [the tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), and that you read our suggestions for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). Your question is a bare problem statement without any of the important context that we expect such as what attempts you made, where you might have got stuck, and what *mathematical* question you can formulate about those attempts.

Comment: @Anonymous Well, what you ended up with is already the answer...almost! Take a little time to think about it.

Comment: Wait, I think I got it. Now I just substitute x with 0 to get $\sqrt{\frac{q}{p}}$

Comment: Indeed so...and why can you "just" substitute $\;x\;$ for $\;0\;$ ? Either because of basic continuity results or else because you proved that for this kind of functions. Nice !

Comment: Thanks, should I delete this question? It is not going to be really helpful for anybody, I should've spend some more time on the question too.

Comment: Also observe that double dollar signs in both sides of a formula centers it in the next line and makes the formula bigger and clearer.

Comment: You better leave the question as it is. It could help someone else, why not?

Comment: Thanks guys, that's great @DonAntonio. Will keep that in mind.